# How can i enforce file type uploads with an AWS S3 bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using a bucket policy for AWS S3, is it possible to enforce that the file being uploaded (PutObject) has the file extension ".txt"? If so what would that bucket policy look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
{
  "Version":"2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root" },
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*.txt"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Cheers yegor! This works for defining a single user, but when i try to apply the Principal to a group it fails. The follow up question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063868/aws-s3-bucket-policy-invalid-group-principal